# Cannot find 'Created Before Payment' method (Lovata Paypal Shopaholic plugin for OctoberCms)

Tags: paypal, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have purchased the Paypal Shopaholic plugin and looking at docs: https://octobercms.com/plugin/lovata-paypalshopaholic > Documentation

I can't seem to see where the 'created before payment method' is referred to here?:

[image: looking for 'Created before payment' method]

Is there an example of setting up a Paypal payment in the docs somewhere?
(cant seem to see any Paypal docs here: https://shopaholic.one/docs#/plugins/home)

Also, is there a way to create a Paypal subscription (instead of just a once-off order) ?

Any help much appreciated,
gvanto

Edit: After creating a payment method, there doesn't seem to be anywhere to put the generated token:

[image: no field to enter token]

Answer (score 0):

Well that's one of the worst Usage instructions I've ever seen for a shopping cart -- but by "token" perhaps they are referring to a REST client_id and secret from a Live app, created in [the Developer Dashboard for your account.](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications)

Comment: The token is not the problem (that part is clear), it's where the 'created before payment' is...

Comment: Well that's what you created in Step 1.

Comment: that's what I thought initially but can't see anywhere to put the token (see screenshot) attached.

Comment: You'll need to contact Shopaholic for support, since their instructions are thoroughly unclear and insufficient.